# Differential Equations - Elementary Application

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a Mechanics Problem. Kindly help. I'm almost there.

A ball is thrown upward with an initial velocity of 49 m/s. Find the velocity after 3 seconds. Find its maximum height. Compute the time it takes for the ball to return to its original point. Use g= 9.8 m/s^2 .

Using the formula:
a= dv/dt

By integration, I got:
v= at + vsub0

By integrating it again for the second time, wherein v= (ds/dt), I got:
s= 1/2at^2 + tVsub0 + Ssub0.

I got v(3)= 19.6 m/s. Is it correct?

What will be my s at s= -1/2 gt^2 + 49t + 0 to compute for t? 
Is it 0? If it is 0, t will be 0 too, isn't it?

And what formula should I use to get the maximum height?
I tried solving it using physics formula H=[vi^2(sin^2theta)]/2g and I got 122.38. Which is wrong.. Correct answer is approx 5m.. How can I derive my formula using suvat equations?

Comment: Do you have any concept of uniform acceleration movement?

Comment: You need to use suvat equations

Comment: What have you done? Figure out how the 3 equations of uniform acceleration along a straight line  $ v= u+ a t, \, v^2-u^2= 2 a s, \, s = u t + at^2/2,  a= -g = -9.81 $ are derived/obtained. Also to start, $ \ddot s = -g\, $

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int \frac{d^2s}{dt^2} = \int -g ~dt $$

$$ \int \frac{ds}{dt} =\int -gt+C $$

At $t=0$ $ \frac{ds}{dt}=49$ $\implies C=49$

$$ \int \frac{ds}{dt} =\int -gt+49 $$

$$ s = \frac{-gt^2}{2}+49t+K $$

Assuming it starts from rest $$ s=0 , t=0 \therefore K = 0$$

Hence $s=\frac{-gt^2}{2}+49t$

Can you solve your problems from here?

Comment: I got v(3)= 19.6 m/s. Is it correct? What will be my s at s= -1/2 gt^2 + 49t + 0 to compute for t? And what formula should I use to get the maximum height?